# How to count repeating functions in a for loop, Discord.py

Tags: python, random, discord.py

I am trying to create a Discord slot bot where if 2 of the emojis match the bot rewards the user a prize and if all 3 then multiply the prize by 3x. However in order to do this I need to check and see if my function is repeating any values, ive looked online for an answer and the closed thing I found to what I think I needed was *.count* *if description_text.count(i):* and then if two or more matched payout x2 etc. but since my function is a int and not a string it does not work. I also tried counting the list but at last that only returned false since the list is unique.

I was wondering if you anyone had any insight on how I might be able to see if the emojis are repeating and then if they are how to payout the prizes accordingly. Thanks!

```
final = [
    "||:watermelon:||", #0
    "||:lemon:||", #1
    "||:tangerine:||", #2
    "||:apple:||", #3
    "||:pineapple:||", #4
]

description_text = ""

for i in range(3):
    description_text = f"{description_text} {random.choices(final, cum_weights=(0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), k=1)[0]}"
    
embed = discord.Embed(title="Slot Machine", description= description_text, color=0x00d9ff)
embed.set_footer(text="Use !lottery to see how Prizes work!")
await ctx.send(embed=embed)

if description_text.count(i):
    await update_bank(ctx.author,2*amount)
    await ctx.send(f'You won :slight_smile: {ctx.author.mention}')
else:
    await update_bank(ctx.author,-1*amount)
    await ctx.send(f'You lose :slight_frown: {ctx.author.mention}')
```

**Error Message:** discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: *TypeError: must be str, not int*

Comment: Maybe .. [typecasting](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_casting.asp) would help for  ` TypeError: must be str, not int ` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to re-write slightly. Rather than storing each slot result by adding them onto the end of a string, generate them all separately:

```py
slot1, slot2, slot3 = random.choices(final, cum_weights=(0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), k=3)
```

Then, it should be simple to check if any of your slots are equal.  You'll just need to build up the output string from the three `slot` variables:

```py
description_text = f"{slot1}{slot2}{slot3}"
```

Comment: Hi there, Roadie Rich I went ahead and re-wrote the query however when I go to run it now the emoji is always the first one in the list and it does not look like it is selecting it randomly? do you know what the cause of this might be?

Comment: final = [        " 
        "||:watermelon:||", #0
        "||:lemon:||", #1
        "||:tangerine:||", #2
        "||:apple:||", #3
        "||:pineapple:||", #4
    ]
    slot1, slot2, slot3 = random.choices(final, cum_weights=(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), k=3)
    description_text = f"{slot1} {slot2} {slot3}"
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Slot Machine", description = description_text, color=0x00d9ff)
    embed.set_footer(text="Use !lottery to see how Prizes work!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if slot1 == slot1 or slot2 == slot2 or slot3 == slot3:
etc.

Comment: You need to use the `weights` argument rather than `cum_weights` in the `random.choices` call.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out!